# Sortng array by order to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays:

Main array:

```
const items = [
  "Лопата 123",
  "Empty Forest",
  "Forever young",
  "My ears",
  "Most Important",
  "16 Tons",
  "Operation Flashpoint",
  "Prize A1",
  "Нарешті літо",
];
```

And keys array:

```
const keys = ["Prize A1", "Forever young", "Most Important"];
```

I want to sort the first array in the order of the key array, for example:

```
const expected = [
  "Prize A1",
  "Forever young",
  "Most Important",
  "Лопата 123",
  "Empty Forest",
  "My ears",
  "16 Tons",
  "Operation Flashpoint",
  "Нарешті літо",
]
```

I writed some code, but it doesn’t work as it should:

```
const expectedOrder = items.sort(function(a, b) {
   return keys.indexOf(b) - keys.indexOf(a);
});
```

```js
 const items = [
    "Лопата 123",
    "Empty Forest",
    "Forever young",
    "My ears",
    "Most Important",
    "16 Tons",
    "Operation Flashpoint",
    "Prize A1",
    "Нарешті літо",
  ];
    
const keys = ["Prize A1", "Forever young", "Most Important"];

const expectedOrder = items.sort(function(a, b) {
   return keys.indexOf(b) - keys.indexOf(a);
});

console.log('expectedOrder', expectedOrder)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort with a default value for `-1` indices.

```js
 const
     items = ["Лопата 123", "Empty Forest", "Forever young", "My ears", "Most Important", "16 Tons", "Operation Flashpoint", "Prize A1", "Нарешті літо"],
     keys = ["Prize A1", "Forever young", "Most Important"];

items.sort((a, b) => ((keys.indexOf(a) + 1) || Number.MAX_VALUE) - ((keys.indexOf(b) + 1) || Number.MAX_VALUE));

console.log(items);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

An even shorter approach takes an object for sorting with a default value.

```js
 const
     items = ["Лопата 123", "Empty Forest", "Forever young", "My ears", "Most Important", "16 Tons", "Operation Flashpoint", "Prize A1", "Нарешті літо"],
     order = { "Prize A1": 1, "Forever young": 2, "Most Important": 3, default: Number.MAX_VALUE };

items.sort((a, b) => (order[a] || order.default) - (order[b] || order.default));

console.log(items);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` your `keys`:

- `"Prize A1"` = 0
- `"Forever young"` = 1
- `"Most Important"` = 2

`sort` puts the item higher if the value is greater than 0, but in your case `"Prize A1"` < `"Most Important"`

You can reverse your `keys` array:

```js
const items = [
    'Лопата 123',
    'Empty Forest',
    'Forever young',
    'My ears',
    'Most Important',
    '16 Tons',
    'Operation Flashpoint',
    'Prize A1',
    'Нарешті літо',
];

const keys = ['Prize A1', 'Forever young', 'Most Important'].reverse();

const expectedOrder = items.sort(function(a, b) {
    return keys.indexOf(b) - keys.indexOf(a);
});

console.log('expectedOrder', expectedOrder);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the items are included in your keys array.

If **both** are included or not included then the **order is kept unchanged** **else** the item included in keys must be placed **before** in the list.

```js
 const items = [
    "Лопата 123",
    "Empty Forest",
    "Forever young",
    "My ears",
    "Most Important",
    "16 Tons",
    "Operation Flashpoint",
    "Prize A1",
    "Нарешті літо",
  ];
    
const keys = ["Prize A1", "Forever young", "Most Important"];

const expectedOrder = items.sort(function(a, b) {
   const incA = keys.includes(a);
   const incB = keys.includes(b);
   
   return (incA === incB)? 0 : ((incA)? -1 : 1);
});

console.log('expectedOrder', expectedOrder)
```